# How do i get data from immutableMultiDict

Tags: python

I would like to understand how can i send a list over a request and get in python.
I tried using request.args.get('keywords') which didnt help. 
Then when i tried request.args, i got

ImmutableMultiDict([('keywords[]', 'divyani'), ('keywords[]', 'object'), ('keywords[]', 'work')])

What i have tried is

Call :

```
var promise = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/' + 'api/v1/resume-anotate/' + url,
            params: {
                "keywords[]": ['divyani', 'object', 'work']
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        }, function (error) {
            return error.data;
        });
```

Request URL :

```
  http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/resume-anotate/file?keywords%5B%5D=divyani&keywords%5B%5D=object&keywords%5B%5D=work
```

Getting Args:

```
   request.args
```

ImmutableMultiDict([('keywords[]', 'divyani'), ('keywords[]', 'object'), ('keywords[]', 'work')])

Comment: Does `request.args.getlist('keywords[]')` work

Comment: Checkout the post at : https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/4krfu0/afconvert_immutablemultidict_to_properly/

Comment: @Ryan request.args.getlist('keywords[]')  worked